# Combobox item (i.e. some username) should map to (i.e. should return) ID on clicking Add button

Tags: winforms, powershell, combobox

Right now the text written in combobox (i.e.ID) onclick adds the same text as

```
$b = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$b.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::Simple
$a = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$a.add_click({
    if(-not $b.Items.contains($b.Text)) {
        $b.Items.Add($b.Text)
    }
    $b.Text = ''
    $b.Focus()
})
```

I'm using .NET binding to populate the data i.e. .dll file.

If I write username in the combobox, it should map to the ID and on `add_click` button the ID should be returned.

Please let me know if you need more information on this or to know what all things I tried.

Comment: What is `$Users`? Also, could you show how you do the DataSource/DataBindings part?

Comment: I'm just checking the local path where .dll file resides like this `add-type -path $some_path  -ErrorAction Stop` @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: How does that relate to the ComboBox's DataSource?

Comment: Right now there is no source for combobox, I'm just taking a text and adding it on click. We can extract data source using select statements.

Comment: You should *always* explain what you already tried and why that didn't work, so people won't waste their time suggesting it again, or point out mistakes you made with the approach. You should also *always* make code samples in your questions [self-contained](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can reproduce the problem.